# Returned results from JSON to insert into mysql table and then email the results

Tags: php, mysql, json, sendmail

I need help with how to insert the returned results of a JSON array into an sql table and then email the results returned.

Below is my php script so far that successfully gets the results of a query into a JSON array

```
<?php

    // set up the connection variables
    $db_name  = 'dbanme';
    $hostname = 'host';
    $username = 'username';
    $password = 'password';

    // connect to the database
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);

    // a query get all the records from the users table
    $sql = 'SELECT tabel1.id,table1.type FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id WHERE table1.id NOT IN ( SELECT table2.id FROM table2)';

    // use prepared statements, even if not strictly required is good practice
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );

    // execute the query
    $stmt->execute();

    // fetch the results into an array
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

    // count number of results returned in the array
    $countresults = count($result);
    echo $countresults;


    if ( $countresults > 0 ) {

    // convert to json
    $json = json_encode( $result );

    // decode the results returned and insert them into table 2

    // email the results returned


    }

    else {
        echo ' no results found';
    }
```

?>

UPDATE :
Table 1 structure :
ID INT 10
Type VARCHAR 50

Table 2 structure :
ID INT 10
Type VARCHAR 50

I realised I dont need to encode result into JSON but I still cant get the code to get the results returned from an array and insert them into tabl2 and then email the results straight after.

Comment: You could use the results for the email and add a query to `insert` the rows directly into `table2`. There doesn't seem to be a need to decode them if all you are going to do is send it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to tell us why you converted the results to json in the first place. You already have an array, you don't need a JSON string in your case.

Anyhow, you convert a JSON string back to an array like this:

```
$yourArray = json_decode($json)
```

Now you say you want to insert the data into table two. I don't know how your table looks like, but if I look at your code, I guess your sql would look something like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table2(id, type) VALUES (:id, :type)';
```

So your code would look something like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table2(id, type) VALUES (:id, :type)';
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $yourArray ['id']);
$stmt->bindParam(':type', $yourArray['type']);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->execute();
```

If you want to send the results via mail, you just use the default mail function:

```
$to = 'RECIEVER@MAIL'
$subject = 'SUBJECT';
$message='Your values are: '.$yourArray ['id'].' - '.$yourArray['type'];

mail($to,$subject,$message);
```

If the default mail function doesn't work, your server may not allow it (sometimes for security reasons). In this case I recommend using a third party library like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Your question did not reveal many informations, I did the best I could but the code above is still more of a pseudocode.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. You are correct there is no point of encoding the result into JSON.

Comment: O tried doing the code you gave me but i get the a syntax erro -Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: My code above is not a complete solution, copy/paste won't work. It is meant to push you in the right direction. I suppose my code may have some errors, though I am not seeing it. If anyone finds the error, please correct it.